# In "Supernatural," why does Sam not kill Ruby?

Tags: supernatural

Why doesn't Sam kill Ruby when he had the chance? I mean she lied to him, she's a demon. Sam and Dean hunt demons why?

Comment: Could u expand your question by mentioning the episode and so on?:)

Comment: Not an answer, just a comment really but it was implied throughout the season that Sam had the hots for Ruby (or her meat-suit to be exact) and there was that whole issue with the demon blood...